# What does the height mean in a tensorboard histogram

Tags: tensorboard

Here https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensorboard_histograms#a_basic_example, it says "For example, in the following image we can see that the histogram at timestep 176 has a bin centered at 2.25 with 177 elements in that bin.
[sample image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCUWI.png)

However, what I saw there are some bins that contains some "half element". By their explanation, the histogram at timestep 35 has a bin centered at 0.221 with 6.88 elements in that bin.[sample image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKzt.png)

So is the height of the histogram in tensorborad really means the number of elements?

Sorry right now I cannot embedded images in my post, so I add some links for those sample images.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you find out what fractional heights mean?

Comment: @Gianluca Micchi. No. Actually I found tensorboard is not that useful.